# Delete object from database automatically if one field is TRUE

Tags: python, django, django-models

Automatically delete an object from the database if one attribute of the object is TRUE.

I've tried Django Signals, but it didn't help.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If I change the "answered" field to TRUE in Admin Panel, then this object must be automatically deleted from the database.

Comment: Why didn't signals help? Sounds like they would be perfect for this.

Comment: Which signal function did you use?

Comment: @cagrias I used pre_delete. Maybe I used it incorrectly.

Comment: you need to use post_save as you are doing save operation on an existing question when changing it to TRUE in django admin.

Comment: @cagrias Then how to delete that object? Could you show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need post_save signals by using something like:

```py
from .models import Question

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Question)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.answered:
        instance.delete()
```

Comment: Shouldnt the sender be `Question` since he wants to delete the instance after the `answered` field of the `Question` model is changed?

Comment: @Stevy That's OK. I understood.